How to correctly use the AND operator in Prometheus to join two queries?
I'm trying to combine two PromQL queries to create alerts and automations in our Openshift clusters, but I'm running into a problem when using the AND operator. The idea is to apply a taint when memory usage goes over a certain threshold, and remove it when it goes under another threshold.
I have a query that checks for a node taint in my worker nodes:
kube_node_spec_taint{effect="PreferNoSchedule",node=~".*worker-.*"}

And one that returns the worker nodes over a certain memory threshold:
(((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"} - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"})/(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"}-4399824896))*100)>85

As I am trying to only get the Openshift nodes that fullfil both conditions (taint applied and over/under a memory threshold), I understand I should be using the AND operator. However, the query returns  No datapoints found.
I am running this:
(((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"} - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"})/(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"}-4399824896))*100)>85 AND label_replace(kube_node_spec_taint{effect="PreferNoSchedule",node=~".*worker-.*"}, "instance", "$1", "node","(.+)")

As you can see I am using the label_replace function to rename a field from the kube_node_spec_taint query, because it's named "instance" instead of "node" in the other query. This works correctly, I get the node names under the instance label.
I've tried inverting the query order, wrapping each one in parenthesis, using another query instead of the memory one... I cannot get Prometheus to only show the node that fulfils both conditions. If I run the queries individually I get the correct results (the same node name under the instance label).
If I run the same query with OR instead of AND, I can see both results in the same result, both under the instance query, but I cant get it to work with AND.
Edit: I feel like the key to make it work is to make both queries return ONLY the "instance" field, but I cannot find a way to do that either.

Solved it!
I managed to combine both queries using the sum by function. It modified the results so I only get the field im summing by (even though there's no addition operation being done).
Final queries look like this:
sum by (instance)((((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"}- node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"})/(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"}-4399824896))*100)>85) unless sum by (instance)((label_replace(kube_node_spec_taint{effect="PreferNoSchedule",node=~".*worker-.*"}, "instance", "$1", "node","(.+)")))

and
sum by (instance)((((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"}- node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"})/(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~".*worker-.*"}-4399824896))*100)<70) AND sum by (instance)((label_replace(kube_node_spec_taint{effect="PreferNoSchedule",node=~".*worker-.*"}, "instance", "$1", "node","(.+)")))


Sounds like what you actually needed was and on(instance)

Thanks! I'll try it out, it might be better.
